# How to change spelling suggestion to en-US in latex + vs code?

Tags: latex, vscode-extensions

I am using VS code + Latex for writing my research papers. I want my spell check to show suggestions in English-US, but the results I am getting are in English-UK. Is there any possible way to configure the language in VS code?

PS: I am using the LaTex Workshop (James Yu) extension in VS code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several VS Code plugins which provide this task. I recommend a couple:

1. [Code Spell Checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker), which supports many programming and markup languages;
2. [LTeX – LanguageTool grammar/spell checking](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=valentjn.vscode-ltex), which supports only a few markup languages.

Both check documents in American English (en-US) by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you have LTeX installed, you just need to type the following at the top of your tex file:

`%LTeX: language=pt-PT`

Just adapt for whatever language you need, e.g., pt-BR, en-GB, etc...

If it still doesn't work, in addition, modify the language, in the LTeX setting, to auto:
[image]

You might also try adding the following to your LaTeX document:

`\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}`

Adapt to your language, obviously.